# How can I flash android_low_ram enabler via adb and fastboot?

Tags: adb, fastboot, android-go

I wanted to know if I could flash the android_low_ram enabler zip file via adb and fastboot as I want to make Android run smoother on my 2gb ram phone which came pre- installed with full Android. I searched on xda for this but couldn't find exact adb command for my purpose.

Links -

1. https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/flash-zip-files-from-adb-terminal-and-other-commands.1353234/
2. android_low_ram enabler zip file --
   https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mod-low-ram-property-patcher-for-android.3737373/

Comment: Is your device bootloader unlocked and/or rooted? Such patches modify the system and can't be installed on unrooted systems.

Comment: https://github.com/TheSkater187/Magisk_Low_Ram

Comment: I have bootloader unlocked but any recovery is not available for my device not it is rooted.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/systemless-root/info

Answer (score 0):

This flashable zip does nothing more than installing some OTA startup script which does modification in `build.prop`

```
ro.config.low_ram=true
```

assuming you have unlocked bootloader you can install flashable zip from custom recovery via fastboot/adb

```
fastboot boot twrp.img
adb push android_lowram_enabler.zip /tmp
adb shell twrp install /tmp/android_lowram_enabler.zip
```

That might however not give the desired result, as OTA script is pushed to `/system/addon.d` which is a non-standard feature of LineageOS custom ROM, and so `ro.config.low_ram`